# About A Kind of Usage of Auxiliary or Helping Verbs

Tags: conditional-constructions, inversion

Why do we write auxiliary or helping verbs at the beginning of a sentence? What are the purposes of it? For example:

> Had Edison known the danger X-rays posed, he may have exercised more caution when experimenting on human subjects.

> Should the filibuster extend past midnight, the senators may not vote on the bill.

Can you explain all the reasons and purposes?

Comment: This is called *conditional inversion*; you may see several questions involving the construction [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%5Binversion%5D+%5Bconditional-constructions%5D)

Answer (score 1):

Those are optional forms, and they are often done just to avoid repetitive syntax.  There is no difference in meaning between "Should the fillibuster extend past midnight, the senators may not vote on the bill" and "If the fillibuster extends past midnight, the senators may not vote on the bill."

Comment: I agree but would give an example with had [past participle] too.